# Conduction Heat transference in a steel bar

Tags: thermodynamics, tensor-calculus

I am making an experiment to evaluate how much time it would take for a circular steel bar (10mm diameter, 20mm lenght) to transfer 800°C from one end to another (the other end is at 30°C).  conduction

Do you know what is the formula that I can use to calculate the necessary time?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clearly defined. What's the meaning of reaching the cold end. For example, if the cold end temperature increases from 30 degrees to 30.1 degrees, can we say this is "reaching"?

In general, for heat conduction problem, you can solve heat conduction problem. 
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial ^2T}{\partial x^2}$$ 
with initial value: 
$$T(x,0)=30$$
and with boundary conditions: 
$$U(0,t)=800$$
$$\frac{\partial T(L,t)}{\partial x}=q$$
Here q is the heat flux from the steel end to the surrounding, which is initially 30 degrees C.

Heat flux on the cold end depends on several scenarios. It can be adiabatic, or can also be free convective, or can be connected to another metal, or there is a blower cooling it. So it depends.